# Symfony 3.0 PostgreSQL Database Error

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony, postgresql-9.5

I am trying to use Symfony 3.0 With a PostreSQL Database.

Parameters.yml:

```
parameters:
    database_driver: pdo_pgsql
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: 5432
    database_name: dmfa
    database_user: username
    database_password: password
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
    mailer_user: null
    mailer_password: null
    secret: a28a9e1bfefb5aa6f7f3be73a9a62c01eedf55ab
```

I run the following code to try and generate and entity:

```
php ./bin/console doctrine:generate:entity
```

Despite changing my drive to pdo_pgsql i get the following errors:

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException]                                          
  An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away 

[Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]                
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away

[PDOException]                                     
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away

[PDOException]                                  
  PDO::__construct(): MySQL server has gone away
```

It feels like i am missing a step because Symfony is still looking for a mysql database. Please give me some insight on how to correct this error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Double check that in your `app/config/config.yml` you have:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   "%database_driver%"
```

Comment: I have corrected that but am not getting the following error [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException]              
  An exception occured in driver: could not find driver

Comment: That means you probably don't have the driver installed on the machine. You can check the available PDO drivers by doing `print_r(PDO::getAvailableDrivers());` in a script.

Comment: Thank you that helped. I also had to do the following: brew install php70-pdo-pgsql in case you installed php7 on mac with brew and, change php version according to what you have installed.